# Mongodb on Google Cloud VM - Debian 9 won't run on VM external IP address

Tags: mongodb, google-cloud-platform, debian

We are trying to run MongoDB on a Debian 9 VM on Google Cloud. Our goal is to allow developers access MongoDB on remotely.

We assigned a static, external IP to the vm 35.184.229.10.

In VM's shell, this command `mongo -u admin -p password 127.0.0.1/admin` **WORKS**

```
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/admin?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
Implicit session: session { "id" : UUID("949b233e-3b2d-47ca-9e4c-d658cf25deb3") }
MongoDB server version: 4.0.10
>
```

but if we use external ip address, it shows error as below:

`mongo -u admin -p password 35.184.229.10/admin`

Error message

```
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
connecting to: mongodb://35.184.229.10:27017/admin?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
2019-06-19T21:13:47.055+0000 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to 
server 35.184.229.10:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error 
connecting to 35.184.229.10:27017 :: caused by :: Connection timed out
: connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:344:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
```

Related info:

1. The `/etc/mongod.conf` file has these included:

```
net:
 port: 27017
 bindIp: 0.0.0.0 (we also tried with bindIpAll)

security:
 authorization: 'enabled'
```

2. Running **mongo** command shows it's running on 127.0.0.1

```
oot@instance-1:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.10
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?gssapiServiceName=mongodb
```

What are we missing?

Comment: Did you open a firewall port? If you are trying to connect to the public IP address from inside the VM, you cannot. The VM does not have a public IP address. The public IP address is assigned to a special One-to-One NAT and you are on the private side of that NAT device. Test from a system external to your VM.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, i added the port to firewall (ingress - IP ranges: 0.0.0.0/0 - tcp:27017 - allow). And the same error even when trying from external machines.

Comment: 1/2 I recommend deleting `net.bindIp` and using `net.bindIpAll`. If you can connect to `127.0.0.0` this means that the software is correctly configured and responding on `localhost`. You state that you are listening on `0.0.0.0` which is the correct binding method to listen on all network interfaces. This means that something is blocking access to your software on port 27017.

Comment: 2/2 This problem is caused by either a private Linux firewall or a Google Cloud public firewall blocking access or mis-configured software. Try again connecting to the Private IP address inside the machine. Then try again with the Private IP address from another machine in the same VPC.

Comment: I updated to net.bindIpAll, restarted. Also checked ```netstat -pln | grep 27017``` shows ```unix 2 [ ACC ] STREAM LISTENING 17856 2826/mongod /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock```. I can also ping the ip address. Will try to reinstall mongo, maybe the last option

Comment: You last comment shows that MongoDB is listening on a unix socket, but not a TCP address.

Comment: Copied the wrong one.. ```tcp - 0 - 0 - 127.0.0.1:27017  - 0.0.0.0:*  - LISTEN -  1108/mongod```

Comment: Your MongoDB is NOT listening on `0.0.0.0`. It is listening on `localhost`. You have configured MongoDB wrong.

Comment: I followed this https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/ using `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` ,i cannot find options to specify an ip address. Will try again. The docs are not complete

Comment: You don't specify an IP address for listeners (there are exceptions). You specify network adapters to listen on. `127.0.0.1` which is the same as `localhost` is your local loopback IP address. `0.0.0.0` means listen on all network adapters. You are leaving some configuration detail out as `0.0.0.0` is sufficient. Your configuration is only listening to localhost. Reboot the system and see if the network fixes itself (orphaned process tying up the port, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

After several trials, was able to resolve the issue.

- Before running `mongod` service for first time, update the `/etc/mongo.conf` file with the bingIP you wish. We used `bindIp: 0.0.0.0` or `bindIpAll: true`

Not sure if this is a bug, but will raise a ticket with MongoDB community.

As a summary, steps to uninstall and install Mongo on Debian (ref: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/ )

1. `sudo service mongod stop`
2. `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`
3. `sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb` and `sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb`
4. `echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/debian stretch/mongodb-org/4.0 main" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list`
5. `sudo apt-get update`
6. `sudo apt-get install mongodb-org` (i did not use **-y** option)
7. **Edit the conf file** `/etc/mongod.conf` and add `bindIp: 0.0.0.0` or `bindIpAll: true`
8. `sudo service mongod enable` and `sudo service mongod start`
9. `sudo service mongod status` to check if Mongo is running.

Now access `mongo` , create a test user.

You can test the access to the mongo from a different system. A sample command can be like this `mongo -u admin -p password 35.184.229.10/admin`